# React-native useContext get undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

I try to use Context API in react native peoject, but I don't know why I get undefined.

Here is my code, also can run in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-cookies-mufp9x?file=/src/App.js) here.

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

const FakeContext = createContext();

const FakeProvider = (props) => {
  const [event, setEvent] = useState({ text: "Hello!", name: "molly" });

  return (
    <FakeContext.Provider value={event}>{props.children}</FakeContext.Provider>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const storedEvents = useContext(FakeContext);
  console.log(storedEvents); //undefined
  return (
    <View>
      <FakeProvider>{/* <Text>{storedEvents}</Text> */}</FakeProvider>
      <View>
        <Text>LOGIN~~~~~</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssx8U.png)

Comment: The component in which `useContext` is used must be a child of the context provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it in the fakeprovider child elements:

see below the new component- NewStore.

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

const FakeContext = createContext();

const FakeProvider = (props) => {
  const [event, setEvent] = useState({ text: "Hello!", name: "molly" });

  return (
    <FakeContext.Provider value={event}>{props.children}</FakeContext.Provider>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const storedEvents = useContext(FakeContext);
  console.log(storedEvents); //undefined
  return (
    <View>
      <FakeProvider><NewStore />{/* <Text>{storedEvents}</Text> */}</FakeProvider>
      <View>
        <Text>LOGIN~~~~~</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const NewStore = () => {
  const storedEvents = useContext(FakeContext);
  console.log(storedEvents); 
  return <div>new store</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: @MOLLY if this help please approve answer, it will help me. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough reputation to do that, When I click up button I got this : 
' Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded. '

Comment: Oh I see , there is a tick I can click. (Is that true? lol)